# New to DirectX, custom class broken

Tags: c++, directx

I am new to the Stack Overflow, and while I've been writing basic and intermediate level C++ programs for a few years, I've never been able to move beyond that. I recently learned about how to work in DirectX through a Framework that I got from www.planetchili.net. I am trying to develop something similar to an Asteroid's type game for a programming class that will demonstrate AI and pathfinding. Instead of blowing up asteroids, the player would be dog fighting other triangular ships.

The framework comes with a Game object through which I've been doing most of my work. However, I realized that I should probably write my own class for the Ship, which would contain the variables necessary to perform Ship related actions, like drawing the ship and tracking stats like position and score.

However, I'm running into a problem that seems to be like an Inception-level paradox. The framework uses something called D3Dgraphics, and it declares and uses a D3D object called gfx. In order to make use of the D3D drawing functions in Ship, I included the D3D library and created a D3D object in Ship.h.

I can declare and instantiate the Ship object in Game, but the drawing functions which work when used directly in game, do not work when used via the ship object. I have no idea why this is, but I believe it may be because of this nasty web I've weaved. The Game objected uses a D3D object which has a function called Go() that seems to draw and destroy the frame, The Ship object uses a D3D object but does not have access to Game's Go() method, and then Game uses Ship.

Here's a bit of the code I have... Please straighten me out.

```
Ship.cpp
    //Ship.cpp
    #include "Ship.h"
    #include <math.h>
    enter code here
    //Constructor
    Ship::Ship(HWND hWnd)
    :   gfx ( hWnd )
    {}
    void Ship::drawLine(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
    //Draws a line using gfx.putPixel- This function works perfectly if declared and used directly in Game.cpp
    }

Ship.h
    //Ship.h
    #pragma once

    #include "D3DGraphics.h"
    #include "Keyboard.h"
    #include <vector>

    class Ship{
    private:
        D3DGraphics gfx;
    public:
        Ship::Ship(HWND hWnd); //Default Constructor
    };




 //Game.h
    #pragma once
    #include "Ship.h"
    #include "D3DGraphics.h"
    #include "Keyboard.h"

    class Game
    {
    public:
        Game( HWND hWnd,const KeyboardServer& kServer );
        void Go();
        //Member functions
    private:
        void ComposeFrame();

    private:
        D3DGraphics gfx;
        KeyboardClient kbd;
        Ship psp;
    };

//Game.cpp
#include "Game.h"
#include <math.h>

Game::Game( HWND hWnd,const KeyboardServer& kServer )
:   gfx ( hWnd ),
    psp(hWnd),
    kbd( kServer )
{}

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    psp.drawShip();
}
```

Comment: I probably should have specified. My code compiles, and psp.drawShip() appears to be accepted by the code, but nothing happens in the window when I run it. There should be, at the very least and bounding circle drawn in the middle with a red orientation vector, but the window is blank. I'm not sure what to do to get to use my Ship Object in Game.

Comment: Without being familiar with the framework you're using, we can't do much to help. Guessing at common issues, I can suggest making sure `::Present` is called somewhere and the framework is initializing your window and render surfaces correctly, then check your coordinates and vertexes for oddities.

Answer (score 1):

The `D3DGraphics` object your `Game` class is using, is a different one in memory from the `Ship` `D3DGraphics`object. You have to use pointers to make sure you are drawing with the same object, change it to these snippets:

```
    class Ship{
        private:
            D3DGraphics *gfx;
        public:
            Ship::Ship(D3DGraphics *pGfx); //Default Constructor
        };
```

-

```
//Constructor
        Ship::Ship(D3DGraphics *pGfx)
        {
            gfx = pGfx;    
        }
```

-

```
Game::Game( HWND hWnd,const KeyboardServer& kServer )
:   gfx ( hWnd ),
    psp(gfx),
    kbd( kServer )
{}
```

Instead of using `gfx.` you now have to use `gfx->` in your `Ship` class. I.E. `gfx->PutPixel()` instead of `gfx.PutPixel()`.

A little side note, try change your variables names to something that gives more information using the commonly used Hungarian Notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation